# Julia: Function which uses append! modify its argument

Tags: arrays, function, julia, append

I define a function which takes an array as argument, append some values to it and return the appended array.
I see that the array I pass as an argument to the function is modified even though my function does not act directly on it.

Here is a minimal code

```
function test(t)
  y = t
  append!(y, [2])
  return y
end
```

Then, define an array x

```
x = [1]
```

When I call test(x), it returns [1, 2] which is expected but x now has also the value [1, 2], which I don't understand...

Comment: test() mutates x, so x is now changed. Please read about mutating functions in Julia

Comment: But internally, test() only acts on the local variable y, no ? I mean, I understand that append!() is a mutating function but my function test() shouldn't be ?

Comment: `y` *is* `t`. The equals sign assigns `y` to the same underlying array as `t`. You can `copy(t)` or `deepcopy(t)` to get a brand new object. The `!` in the function name is purely convention; it has no syntactic meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In Julia there is a **convention** to add `!` to the function name when it mutates its arguments, see end of this section https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-argument-passing.

However, it is only a **convention** (to show things visually). As is explained in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-argument-passing, no matter how you name the function is uses "pass-by-sharing", which means that `y` points to the same address in memory as `x`.

If you wanted to avoid mutation of `x` you would have to write `y = copy(t)` to create an independent object; or `y = deepcopy(t)` if you wanted to ensure fully new object, including copying of potentially objects that `x` points to.

`y` is a local variable but pointing to the same address in memory as `x` in your original code. So, in other words, `x`, `t`, and `y` in your code are different labels but attached to the same object in memory.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your answer. I was not aware about that "pass-by-sharing" concept.

Comment: This is similar to how Python works, but different from e.g. R, which does copy-on-write.

Comment: Further thinking about it, it was really the statement "y = t" that I did not interpreted correctly. It really means that y points to t. And then, through "pass-by-sharing", t points to x...